# Como alterar propriedade Text de um Button dentro de um for

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-5

estou com uma dúvida em ASP.NET, estou criando um laço de repetição dentro do HTML para que apareçam 60 botões, cada um com um numero diferente no Text, indo de 0 a 59, sendo que depois eu preciso pegar esse texto e colocar numa textbox. Estava fazendo da forma abaixo:

```
<%for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{%>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="0" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    <% Button1.Text = (i + 1).ToString(); 
}%>
```

Mas acontece que quando no evento "Button3_Click" eu faço o código abaixo, a textbox recebe valor 0.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbAssento.Text = Button1.Text;
}
```

Também já tentei declarar uma variável pública que recebesse o valor de i e mandasse para a textbox mas também não funciona. O que eu faço?

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que use o repeater ao invés do for explicito:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpBotoes" OnItemDataBound="rpBotoes_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAssento" runat="server" Text="0" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

E no servidor:

```
protected void rpBotoes_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnAssento") as Button;
    b.Text = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
    b.Click += (senderBtn, eBtn) =>
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "teste", $"alert('{b.Text}')", true);
    };
}
```

Espero que isso ajude.